# How to plot odd ratio from multiple logistic regression with CI in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

I have a model with binary outcome 0,1 and four independent variables and all of them are categorical variables. I want to plot the odd ratio of my glm.

```
My model is glm(outcome ~ v1 + v2 + v3, data = data, family = binomial)
All the variables v1, v2 and v3 have multiple categories.
```

I also found that some people suggest using sjp.glm to plot odds ratio for logistic regression. But I cannot download that package in r 3.6.0.

I've found below code from this website http://www.jscarlton.net/post/2015-10-24VisualizingLogistic/
    The outcome of the plot is pretty similar to what I want to receive. However, I do not want to do it manually. Is there a way to plot the odds ratio of glm model directly?

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create labels
boxLabels = c("Past encounter", "Mutualism WVO:\nNon-hunting wildlife experiences", "Domination WVO:\nEthics of hunting", "Domination WVO:\nWildlife management", "Age", "Education", "Negative attitudes toward box turtles", "Gender")

# Enter summary data. boxOdds are the odds ratios (calculated elsewhere), boxCILow is the lower bound of the CI, boxCIHigh is the upper bound.

df <- data.frame(
  yAxis = length(boxLabels):1,
  boxOdds = c(2.23189,1.315737,1.22866,.8197413,.9802449,.9786673,.6559005,.5929812),
  boxCILow = c(.7543566,1.016,.9674772,.6463458,.9643047,.864922,.4965308,.3572142),
  boxCIHigh = c(6.603418,1.703902,1.560353,1.039654,.9964486,1.107371,.8664225,.9843584)
)

# Plot
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = boxOdds, y = yAxis))
p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 1), size = .25, linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmax = boxCIHigh, xmin = boxCILow), size = .5, height = .2, color = "gray50") +
  geom_point(size = 3.5, color = "orange") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = yAxis, labels = boxLabels) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,7,1) ) +
  coord_trans(x = "log10") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("Odds ratio (log scale)") +
  annotate(geom = "text", y =1.1, x = 3.5, label ="Model p < 0.001\nPseudo R^2 = 0.10", size = 3.5, hjust = 0) + ggtitle("Intention to remove box turtles from the road")
```

package ‘sjp.glm’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)

Comment: `sjp.glm` is not a package, it's a function within the `sjPlot` package.  Try `install.packages("sjPlot"); library("sjPlot"); ?sjp.glm` ... ??  Also: `dotwhisker::dwplot(fitted_model, exponentiate=TRUE)` ?

Comment: I just found an alternative solution using plot_model() it works well for me. Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: If you have a solution, you should post it as an answer to your own question.